# unordered is not removing the style on using class unstyled

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am a beginner in Bootstrap .i am trying to unstyle the list using unstyled class,but it is not removing black-spot on the left most of each option how to remove this black dot please guideline
my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="unstyled">
<li>
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>Option 1
</li>
<li>
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Option 2 
</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3">option3</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4" value="option4">option4</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios5" value="option5">option5</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: The important part is your CSS. Can you provide that?

Comment: there is no css part whole code is this in ul each li element creating a blackspot i want to remove that only.

Comment: I see the bootstrap and jQuery JS files, but where are the CSS files?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Bootstrap 3+

As of Bootstrap 3, you'd use the [**`list-unstyled`**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) class to achieve this.

> **`Unstyled`** -   Remove the default `list-style` and `left-margin` on list items
>   (immediate children only). This only applies to immediate children
>   list items, meaning you will need to add the class for any nested
>   lists as well.

Example:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

---

### Bootstrap 2

If still using Bootstrap 2, you'd use the [`unstyled`](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#typography) class.

> **`Unstyled`** - Remove the default `list-style` and `left padding` on list
>   items (immediate children only).

Example:

```
<ul class="unstyled">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's not really what is asked, if he uses bootstrap, there is already a class for that (list-unstyled for BS3) and adding style on top of bootstrap that does exactly the same kind of defeats the purpose...

Answer (score 7):

first link your bootstrap.css in your html file.
you can search for "list-unstyled" class in bootstrap.css file. bootstrap current version is 3.0.0, so you can remove style from ul this way:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li>
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1"     checked>Option 1
</li>
</ul>
```